# Facebook Video Share stopped working since it posts an image instead of video player on wall

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall, facebook-share

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ4UG.png)I have videos posted on my site that are in my server, but after I press FB share button https://www.sotube.com/player/designers-events-celebs/chanel-fragrances-gabrielle-starring-kristen-stewart 
they are not being shared as videos as they used to be, but they appear on Facebook as an image now instead of our video player showing on facebook wall as it used to.

The code (see under) that we have on our site backend has not changed. All this problem happened in NOV 2017, right after I changed these 3 other factors.

- 1. I upgraded my joomla version
- 2. I upgraded my video player component version but their coders say nothing is wrong on their new version.
- 3. I upgraded my server from PHP 5.4.43 and changed to using Apache 5.6. to accommodate the Joomla PHP security upgrade to PHP 5.6. The Apache has a free ssl. So maybe I'm having something with the security levels of encryption of my server. Could you please confirm the requirements[Type of encryption like DSA, RSA, SHA etc, and the number of bits for encryption [1024 or 2048]] for the SSL certificate required for my FB video share? All I know I have a secured page, see [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ4UG.png)

Therefore since it was all previously working before the changes above we contact you to see what can be the issue and kindly check my code just in case that's missing something I should add today.
Thank you

```
    $document->addCustomTag('<link rel="canonical" href="' . $instance->toString() . '"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<link rel="image_src" href="' . $fb . '"/>');

    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="' . PLAYERPATH . '?baserefJHDV=' . $details1 ['baseurl'] . '&id='. $this->videodetails->id .'&playlist_auto=false&showPlaylist=false&shareIcon=false&email=false&zoomIcon=false&playlist_autoplay=false&videoID=0&embedplayer=true" />');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video" content="' . PLAYERPATH . '?baserefJHDV=' . $details1 ['baseurl'] . '&id='. $this->videodetails->id .'&playlist_auto=false&showPlaylist=false&shareIcon=false&email=false&zoomIcon=false&playlist_autoplay=false&videoID=0&embedplayer=true" />');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video:url" content="' . PLAYERPATH . '?baserefJHDV=' . $details1 ['baseurl'] . '&id='. $this->videodetails->id .'&playlist_auto=false&showPlaylist=false&shareIcon=false&email=false&zoomIcon=false&playlist_autoplay=false&videoID=0&embedplayer=true"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:video:height" content="720"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:image" content="' . $video_preview . '"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:description" content="' . $video_desc . '"/>');

    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="fb:app_id" content="111111111111111"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:site_name" content="' . $siteName . '"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:url" content="' . $instance->toString() . '"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:title" content="' . $video_title . '"/>');
    $document->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>');
```

Comment: Facebook is in the process of phasing this out, to keep users' news feeds "cleaner". That such link posts only show the thumbnail, and when clicked lead the user to the external site where they can then play the video, is the desired behavior now.

Comment: Hi CBroe kindly read again above I added more info to my post...also kindly show me where FB officially states that because what you wrote has always been the response for people that have been having my issue since 2014 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5295ec6649b176982419546
and mine just happened 6 months ago after I made changes above.

Comment: If that was the case no one would be able to post and have their videos anymore and there are many still out there coming from sites via share. Facebook does not go manually eliminating one by one. Its either they take that functionality completely out or not. As of now they have not.